# transform.LookAt and Quaternion.LookRotation are flipping the body's rotation when looking?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need help please, the body is flipping even though it is looking the player, I want it to be on the right rotation when looking.

Here is my code! :

```
Vector3 direction = Player.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
```

and also you can watch my video so I can explain it to you clearly!
Please help!

https://streamable.com/ygnbhq

Please watch!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both as described in the API will rotate your object so its **forward** vector is pointing towards the target ... your 3D model seems "wrong" and doesn't have its forward (Z) vector pointing forward by default.

If I look at your model in the video I can see in the rotation Gizmo that your model is rotated by default!

It looks like the forward (Z) vector is pointing up, its right (X) vector is pointing forward and its up (Y) vector is pointing left.

That means in order to be oriented correctly it needs to be additionally rotated about -90° in its local X and -90° in its local Z axis.

You could fix that by adding the rotation needed to again make your object stand upright instead like e.g.

```
transform.LookAt(Player.position);

transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, -90);
```

Comment: waitt ill tryyy

Comment: Thank you very much for idea, it did help me tweaked some stuff from the suggestion you have given :) ...

Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Player.position.x, transform.position.y, Player.position.z);
     
      transform.LookAt(direction);
         transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-80, 0,-80);

this is now my modified code, I am kinda having trouble understanding the quaternions with regards to lookat and quaternion lookrotation, but thanks :) appreciate it!

Comment: Btw `Vector3` is a `struct` so you can simply use `Vector3 direction = Player.position;` ;) no need to go through the constructor